# What helicopter is this in The Walking Dead?

Tags: helicopter, aircraft-identification

The reason I am asking this is because I want to do a 3D model of it. You can see it in this screenshot from [*The Walking Dead*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Walking_Dead_(TV_series)). At first I thought it was a [UH-1H](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_UH-1_Iroquois), but the main rotor doesn't look anything like a UH-1H main rotor.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[image]
([Source](http://www.casperplatoon.com/UH1.1.jpg))

It is a UH-1 Huey.

> ... in the first episode of this sci-fi horror TV series about zombies in Atlanta, we see a pair of US army UH-1 Huey transports, painted with 'air cavalry' insignia, have been abandoned in a hospital car park.— [rotaryaction.com](http://www.rotaryaction.com/pages/walkdead.html)

Looks like the main rotor has sunk down, should be higher up. Maybe a salvaged gearbox caused it to drop. Otherwise it's the same aircraft.